# Mocha test on simple code fails when for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

This is a sort of an online programming test. The system allows you to write a solution to problems and checks it against it's (the platform's internal) unit tests.

Here is the summary of the problem:

> To write a function that takes 2 params (x, y).
>
> If x is greater than y, it **returns an array of even numbers**
>   between x and y.
>
> If x is lesser than y, it **returns an array of odd numbers** between
>   x and y.
>
> If x and y are equal, or if the input is invalid/not integers, **it
>   returns an empty array.** The resulting array is exclusive of x and y
>   in each case.
>
> For instance, if x, y are integers 10, 2, the function would return
>   all the even numbers between 2 and 10 i.e [4, 6, 8].

Here is my code:

```
const numGame = (x, y) => {
  let result = [];
  if (!Number.isInteger(x) || !Number.isInteger(y)) {
    return result;
  }
  if (x > y) {
    for(let i = y + 1; i < x; i++)
      if(i%2 == 0) result.push(i);
  }
  if (x < y) {
    for(let i = x + 1; i < y; i++) {
      if(i%2 == 1 || i%2 == -1) result.push(i); 
    } 
  }

  return result;
}
```

Here are my own tests that pass easily:

```
describe('Challenge', function() {
  it('should return the right array', function() {
    assert.deepEqual(numGame(2,12), [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);
    assert.deepEqual(numGame(12, 2), [4, 6, 8, 10]);
    assert.deepEqual(numGame(-6, 12), [-5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);
    assert.deepEqual(numGame(12, -4), [-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]);
    assert.deepEqual(numGame(0,0), []);
  });
});
```

My tests above pass, but when I submit my code, it fails the internal tests and returns the following:

```
should return the right array
  expected [ Array(9) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]
```

The error seems strange. There's no way to see the code my solution is tested against so it's really frustrating. Please, review my solution to see if there are any edge cases that it's not handling, and maybe provide a better solution/algorithm.

I would also like to know if there's a chance that the platform's internal test might be wrong in some way? Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more details about the specification.
1) "If y is greater than y" is probably a mistake, and should read "if x is greater than y".
2) Are the limits inclusive or exclusive? In other words, is "between 1 and 3" equal to [1, 2, 3] or [2].
3) What happens when x == y?

Comment: @SamiHult, thanks for pointing out the blanks, I just edited the the question. Can you please take a look now?

Comment: It seems to me that the code works as expected. The feedback from the testing machine suggests that either you have misread some of the instructions (array lengths 9 vs. 11 could mean that the limits are inclusive, after all) or that the test case is on the remote machine is, in fact, faulty. If you are sure that you understood the instructions correctly, I suggest that you raise a concern about the validity of the test.

Comment: @SamiHult, the instructions were clear enough, even sample tests provided by the platform indicates that. It turns out that the platform's test is in fact wrong. I edited the code to include x and y, and the test passed. I always thought I was a shitty developer!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the platform's test against which my code is tested, is in fact wrong. I edited the code to include x and y, and the test passed.